# How to search filter date objects with ngTable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ngtable

I have a table similar to this:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
    <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{'userName':'text'}" sortable="'userName'">{{user.userName}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Created'" filter="{'userCreated':'text'}" sortable="'userCreated'">{{user.userCreated | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using `ngTable` and `Angular`, this produces a table based on the data I put provide. It allows the user to search each column using a text input. However the search filter does not work on the `Created` column because it is a javascript date object (that has been filtered to display in a  different format). How can I make search filtering work for dates?

My ngTable function looks like this:

```
function userTable(){

  var data = $scope.userList;

  //init ng-table with data
  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 10
  }, {

    //data length and filters
    total: data.length,
    getData: function($defer, params) {

      //search filter
      var filteredData = params.filter() ?
          $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) :
          data;

      //order filter
      var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
          $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
          data;

      //resolve data
      params.total(orderedData.length);
      $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }

  });
}
```

Then I just call `usertable(someData);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest thing to do is to add another field into your (view) model that would keep formatted date.

so your model would look like :

```
{ Name: '', Created: '', CreatedFormatted: ''}
```

---

another apporach ... create custom comparator that would be used in filter :

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)

params.filter() returns object like {Created: "Mon 12,"}
```

inside the comparator format date for each record and compare strings ...

Comment: Ah yes option 1 was fairly simple. Thanks.